# Downloads stack progress bar "stuck" at 100% after completion of downloads

Tags: macos, dock

[image]

As you can see, the downloads stack's progress indicator is at 100%, and is permanently stuck there even after the completion of all downloads. The only way I can remove the progress bar is by restarting dock (`killall Dock`) or rebooting. Is there any reason this is occurring and/or any way to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug with Google Chrome that seems to have been fixed. Make sure your Chrome is up to date.

- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=150743

Comment: I use Safari usually D:

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of [What is this line on my dock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159541/what-is-this-line-on-my-dock) and [Can't get rid of incomplete download bar underneath dock icon](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64479/cant-get-rid-of-incomplete-download-bar-underneath-dock-icon)

It doesn't just happen with Chrome.

[FinderDock](https://github.com/DaniMol/Restart-Finder-Dock/releases) is a good solution.

Or you can just move the Downloads icon to a different place on the dock, then move it back, that usually fixes it.