# What is this line on my dock?

Tags: macos, dock

I recently upgraded to Yosemite and I seem to have some sort of line on my desktop near the dock that won't go away.  I've changed my background, moved the dock and even rebooted and it stays there.  It looks like something that I can click on and drag up but it doesn't do anything if I click on it.  Did I install something that is causing this? [image: Gray line in dock]

Comment: The vertical or horizontal line in your picture?  The vertical one is a divider between your apps and documents and the horizontal one is a progress bar for a download.

Comment: Try `killall Dock` in Terminal.app. I sometimes get the same progress bar under Downloads folder in Dock and it doesn't go away after finishing downloads.

Comment: Thanks, Mateusz Szlosek!  That worked.  I was referring to the horizontal bar.  Even when I changed the dock to the left or right side it still stayed on the bottom so I knew something was wrong.

Comment: I had it on my launchpad button - moving its position on the dock eliminated it as mpmchugh suggested.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is a progress bar under **Downloads** folder. It sometimes doesn't go away after completing the downloads. One solution for this is to enter this command in **Terminal**:

```
killall Dock
```

This will reset the **Dock**.

Answer (score 9):

Moving the downloads folder to a new position on the Dock and then moving it back takes care of the problem without using Terminal. Great solution for non-technical people! :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem persists since Mavericks. I really don't know why Apple hasn't fixed this yet. The only workaround that I know of is a restart or the killall Dock command in terminal.