# Unable to remove .part files from Downloads stack

Tags: finder, dock

I'm aware that `.part` files are partial downloads. In my case they are coming from Firefox.

[image: .part files in stack]

But these files *only* appear in my Downloads stack and I can't seem to get rid of them. Dragging them to the trash bin does nothing. Clearing all downloads in Firefox does nothing. Restarting Firefox and macos does nothing. Force quitting Finder and relaunching it does nothing. They don't show up in Finder windows, only in the stack.

Even in Terminal, if I attempt to delete them...

```
cd ~/Downloads
rm -f *.part
```

...they still appear in the stack (not to mention `ls -a` reveals nothing)

How can I get rid of these? (macos Ventura 13.0.1)

Comment: I was able to find this question which answers it. The solution was `killall Dock` https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/116071/423768

Comment: It's not a perfect duplicate, but I've gone ahead and flagged it as a duplicate so it'll resolve this question